# Update or change text within elements in a div using JavaScript and DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Okay, so on my webpage I am trying to update the text within a div contained within these span elements.

```
<div class="output-1-2-1-1">
 <p id="yourNameDisplay">Person</p>
</div>
<div class="output-1-2-1-2">
 <p>Born in <span id="yourMonthDisplay">February</span></p>
</div>
```

My current method of doing this is as follows. Input is registered from textboxes using these statements in a function after a button is clicked. I have checked and the id "yourMonth" does match the input box, so that's not the issue.

```
var yourMonth = document.getElementById("yourMonth").value;
```

And then the variable is then displayed by calling the element ID in the same function below.

```
document.getElementById("yourMonthDisplay").innerHTML = yourMonth;
```

But for some reason, the variables aren't showing up in the text after the button is clicked. I have checked to make sure that they are there using a completely separate div in another location and they pop up there fine. I called them and displayed them using the same method and they work fine, as follows:

```
document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = yourMonth;
```

Is there an alternate method you could recommend for displaying these variables that is better?

Comment: This is not immediately reproducible based on the information provided - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L7ojdqma/ . Please provide a coherent [mre] of the issue, rather than just some isolated lines of code. It appears the context will be significant to your issue. See also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: My first guess is there's another element somewhere in your code with the same id `yourMonthDisplay`, but without the rest of your code it's impossible to say. Please include the relevant parts of the rest of your code.

Comment: can you shown us your input field?

Comment: Okay, when I tried it in Fiddle, it's working, there's something in my file that's messing it up. Thank you for showing me that, and next time I will make sure to include more context along with a Fiddle example.

Comment: please DO NOT destroy your own content, that's considered vandalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using innerHTML to put pure text in a span tag. Should work, but perhaps try [innerText](https://www.javatpoint.com/innertext-vs-innerhtml) instead.

```
document.getElementById("output5").innerText = yourMonth;
```

(as mentioned before in the comments, its good to provide more context in your original question)

Answer (score 0):

your event is triggert after click on the button?  if yes, then you get the value from the input field. can you catch the value from the input field? if yes then you can put the new value inside the span tag with the selector **yourMonthDisplay** and not **output5**. you have the wrong selector.

and the code will work.

```js
function swapMonth() {
    let yourMonth = document.getElementById("yourMonth").value;
    document.getElementById("yourMonthDisplay").innerHTML = yourMonth;  
}
```

```html
<input id="yourMonth">
<button onclick="swapMonth(this)">swap</button>

<div class="output-1-2-1-1">
    <p id="yourNameDisplay">Person</p>
</div>

<div class="output-1-2-1-2">
     <p>Born in <span id="yourMonthDisplay">February</span></p>
</div>
```